# SQL MS-Access Select Distinct for multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

sorry for asking on this topic again, but I havent been able to derive a solution to my problem from existing answers.

I have one Table ("`Data`") from which I need to pull three columns ( "`PID`", "`Manager`", "`Customer`" )
and only the "`PID`" has to be distinct. I dont care which records are pulled for the other columns ("`Manger`" / "`Customer`" ) it could be the first entry or whatever.

```
SELECT Distinct PID, Manager, Customer
FROM Data;
```

Will give me all the rows where PID,Manager and Customer are distinct, so if there is two entrys with the same PID but with a different Manager, I will get two records instead of one.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What about these columns data Manager, Customer. Do you want any data for this coulmns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this 
Hope you will find this helpful

```
SELECT PID, max(Manager), max(Customer)
FROM Data
group by PID
```

Or

```
   SELECT PID, min(Manager), min(Customer)
FROM Data
group by PID
```

**EDIT**

I will give you an example to  explain you the `Max & Min Func`

Here is the Sample Table

```
CREATE TABLE data(
    PID int ,
    Manager varchar(20) ,
    Customer varchar(20) 
) ;


insert into data
values
(1,'a','b'),
(1,'c','d'),
(3,'1','e'),
(3,'5','e'),
(3,'3','e')
```

Now,

***These are the Three Queries that will return respective outputs,,***

```
select * from data;


SELECT PID, max(Manager), max(Customer)
FROM Data
group by PID;


  SELECT PID, min(Manager), min(Customer)
FROM Data
group by PID
```

Output for the above queries is

[image]

Explanation : 
**MAX** :

`MAX` is returning `C & 5` for Manager Coz, `C` is greater then `A` & likewise `5` is greater then `1 & 3`

Min fuction is totally opposite of MAX function & is self explenatory.

I have also created on demo Please click to see the demo on Fiddle

[**Click Here To See The Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40007e/1)

Comment: @BobBetter Sorry for the not validated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Hardik Parmar , it works! I wonder though , how does the max() function work on a string? (Manager is a string)

Comment: @BobBetter Max function return the maximum value. Please check the edit that I have done on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT "PID", max("Manager"), max("Customer")
FROM "Data"
GROUP BY "PID";
```

This query returns unique "PID"s and max values of "Manager" and "Customer" for each "PID".

DISTINCT is applied for all the columns from the select list. So you need to use GROUP BY + an aggregate function (returns one value for several rows).

Comment: Thank you @Multisync , it worked after i removed the "". And thank you for your explanation.
Have a great day